# How to Reference Special Characters Using Excel vba

Tags: vba

I have several special characters in an excel spreadsheet. How do I reference them in Excel VBA?

The characters I need are not in the standard 255 ASCII codes.

I was thinking perhaps `Chr(code)` would work, but I'm not able to find the codes for the characters I need to test this.

Comment: you get it using `Chr(number) function`. The opposite function is called `Asc(string)`

Comment: Goto this link to understand the codes for all characters http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: `Sub GetAsciiCodes()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 255
        Range("A" & i) = i
        Range("B" & i) = Chr(i)
    Next

End Sub`

Comment: Nice, but I updated the question because they are non-standard ascii characters

Comment: ++ > The `ChrW` function returns a String containing the Unicode character except on platforms where Unicode is not supported, in which case, the behavior is identical to the `Chr` function.
++ > [Chr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chr-function)
++ 
++ Use [this](https://unicode-table.com/en/) web to search for unicode. 
++ For `ChrW`, just use the numerics in `HTML-code`; dont use the `Unicode number` (idk why).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User `ChrW()` instead of `Chr()` function to reference Unicode characters:

`ChrW(23383)` will produce `字`.

`Chr(23383)` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use this script to see ChrW characters in F column

```
Sub caracter()
Dim caract As String
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Integer
caract = ChrW(633)
For i = 1 To 20000
caract = ChrW(i)
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = caract
Next i
End Sub
```